# Is this matrix diagonalisable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**We will only be looking at one specific eigenvalue**, eigenspace (there are three eigenvalues in total, I know two of them are fine and last one seems not but as I'm not sure I need to ask you).

We have matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
3  & -1 &  0\\ 
2  &  0 &  0\\ 
-2 &  2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1}=1, \lambda_{2}=2, \lambda_{3}=-1$

We will only concentrate on $\lambda_{3}=-1$ because I have checked the others already and I'm very sure they are fine (they show that the matrix is diagonalisable).

We insert $\lambda_{3}=-1$ here $\begin{pmatrix}
3-\lambda  & -1        &  0\\ 
2          &  -\lambda &  0\\ 
-2         &  2        & -1-\lambda
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

Then we get $\begin{pmatrix}
 4  & -1 & 0\\ 
 2  &  1 & 0\\ 
-2  &  2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

$I: 4x-y=0 \Leftrightarrow y=4x$

$II: 2x+y=0$

$III: -2x+2y=0$

We see that there is no value for $z$, so we can choose an arbitrary $z$. We get the eigenspace $E_{A}(-1)=\left\{ \left. \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
4x\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} \right | x,z \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$

Two variables mean the basis is made up by $2$ vectors and this means the dimension of the eigenspace is $2$ and this means the matrix is not diagonalisable because $\lambda_{3}=-1$ is just a single eigenvalue?

---

Can you please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: $x$ is not free: if $y=4x$ then $2x+y=6x$ which must be zero by equation II.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the comment and the edit too. Now I also know how to make this longer line^^

Comment: Do you know how to do row-reduction/Gaussian elimination? That lets you read a basis for the null space of a matrix directly from the rref. I find doing that to be much less error-prone than trying to solve a system of linear equations “by hand.”  In this case, the rref is $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$, from which you can instantly see that the eigenspace is the span of $(0,0,1)^T$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From I and II, we have $y = 4x$ and $y = -2x$.  The only way these can simultaneously hold is if $x = y = 0$.  However, $z$ is indeed a free variable.  We find that
$$
E_A(-1) = \{(0,0,z)^T : z \in \Bbb R\}
$$

Comment: Oh thanks I don't know how I could miss that..! :s But let's say what I did above was correct (the eigenspace), would my reasoning be correct too?

Comment: It would not.  We would indeed conclude that the eigenspace of $-1$ is $2$-dimensional.  If we found that $A$ had another eigenspace with dimension $1$, then the sum of the dimensions is $3$, which means that $A$ is diagonalizable (i.e. has a basis consisting of eigenvectors).

Comment: As an explanatory example: consider the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, which is diagonalizable (since it is diagonal!).  However, every vector from the 2-dimensional $\Bbb R^2$ is an eigenvector associated with $1$, and $1$ is the only eigenvalue.

Comment: Ouch, so there is something I misunderstood badly. The sum of the dimensions always has to be exactly $3$, in every other example where we are working with $3 \times 3$ matrix, and then the matrix is diagonalisable?

Comment: You said that a bit strangely.  A $3 \times 3$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the sum of the dimensions of all eigenspaces is $3$.

Comment: Awesome, now I got it and I will take it to my notes like that. Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: Just one more question if you can reply (not about this question). When I'm supposed to say if a $3 \times 3$ matrix is diagonalisable, and I get $3$ times the same eigenvalue, can I conclude that the matrix is not diagonalisable? Or would that eigenvalue count as $3$ eigenvalues (because we actually get $3$ times the same eigenvalue)?

Comment: @cnmesr If your matrix has exactly one eigenvalue, then it can only be diagonalizable if the entirety of $\Bbb R^3$ is an eigenspace.  In other words: the only diagonalizable matrices with one eigenvalue are multiples of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying that is- no matter how many distinct eigen**values** an by n matrix has, it is diagonalizable if and only if there are n *independent* Eigen**vectors**.  Of course, eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are necessarily independent so if an n by n matrix has n distinct eigenvalues then it must be diagonalizable- but it is the eigenvectors that are important!